# Python, I want to find file each subfolder on a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Example:

```
>>> path = ('datasets/subfolder 1/')
>>> pth = os.listdir(path)
>>> file = pth
>>> while True:
...     for file in pth:
...         print(file)
...     break
>>> 1.jpg, 2.jpg
```

Folder

- subfolder 1
- subfolder 2
- subfolder 3

I want to find file in subfolder 1 next to subfolder 2 and subfolder 3 in python
and I need to get full path :

```
/home/pi/Desktop/datasets/subfolder 1/file jpg
/home/pi/Desktop/datasets/subfolder 2/file jpg
/home/pi/Desktop/datasets/subfolder 3/file jpg
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: This is not enough detail. Please edit and rephrase.

Comment: path = ('datasets/data/')
pth = os.listdir(path)
file = pth

while True:
    for file in pth:
        print(file)
    break

Comment: import os
x = [i[2] for i in os.walk('.')]
y=[]
i=0
for t in x:
    for f in t:
        y.append(f)
while i < len(y):
        print(y[i])
        i+=1
is this what you want?

Comment: Hey @Chatchai.J Did the answer work for you?

Comment: @Quit ,Now I try but have problem with os.scandir not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way, assuming you do not wish to go further down in the tree is:

```
import os

filepaths = []
iterdir = os.scandir(path_of_target_dir)
for entry in iterdir:
    filepaths.append(entry.path)
```

Update:
A list comprehension makes is faster and more compact: (Strongly Recommended)

```
import os

iterdir = os.scandir(path_of_target_dir)
filepaths = [entry.path for entry in iterdir]
```

If you wish to filter by extension:

```
import os

iterdir = os.scandir(path_of_target_dir)
filepaths = [entry.path for entry in iterdir if entry.name.split('.')[-1] =='jpg']  # if you only want jpg files.
```

If you wish to filter by multiple extensions:

```
import os

iterdir = os.scandir(path_of_target_dir)
filepaths = [entry.path for entry in iterdir if entry.name.split('.')[-1] in {'jpg', 'docx'}]  # if you only want jpg and docx files.
```

... or making it easier to read and modify and adding exclude filter:

```
import os

incl_ext = {'jpg', 'docx'}  # set of extensions; paths to files with these extensions will be collected.
excl_ext = {'txt', 'bmp'}  # set of extensions; paths to files with these extensions will NOT be collected.

get_ext = lambda file: file.name.split('.')[-1]  # lambda function to get the file extension.
iterdir = os.scandir(path_of_target_dir)
filepaths = [entry.path for entry in iterdir if get_ext(entry) in incl_ext and get_ext(entry) not in excl_ext]
print(filepaths)
```

You can make it into a function. (You SHOULD make it into a function).